# updating a datetime sql value by exactly a year

Tags: php, sql

im trying to get a datetime variable (example: 2019-02-10 03:13:33) to update exactly a year. i read that datetime is written as a string so i tried to subtract by itself and add +365.

the code works if i take out all "expirationdate" including the bind value. also for some reason, i have to keep my UPDATEs encased in single quotations because theres no changes in my database if they are inside double quotes.

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE usr_customer_profile SET packageid = 3, expirationdate = .'$oneyear'. WHERE usrcustomerid = :usrcustomerid');
 $stmt->bindValue(':expirationdate', $_SESSION['expirationdate'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindValue(':usrcustomerid', $_SESSION['usrcustomerid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $oneyear = (':expirationdate' - ':expirationdate') + 365;
 $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: What happens if the date is Feb 29th?

Comment: To @TheImpaler's point, what does "exactly a year" mean? +365 days? +1 year? +365.25 days? A little vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in PHP or SQL. In PHP you can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or (preferably) the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to add one year to the value in `$_SESSION['expirationdate']`:

```
// using strtotime
$expirationdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_SESSION['expirationdate'] . ' + 1 year'));
// using DateTime
$expiration = new DateTime($_SESSION['expiration_date']);
$expiration->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
$expirationdate = $expiration->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// do the query
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE usr_customer_profile
                      SET packageid = 3, 
                          expirationdate = :expirationdate 
                      WHERE usrcustomerid = :usrcustomerid');
$stmt->bindValue(':expirationdate', $expirationdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':usrcustomerid', $_SESSION['usrcustomerid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$oneyear = (':expirationdate' - ':expirationdate') + 365;
$stmt->execute();
```

In SQL use `+ INTERVAL 1 YEAR` to add 1 year to the expiration date:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE usr_customer_profile
                      SET packageid = 3,
                          expirationdate = :expirationdate + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
                      WHERE usrcustomerid = :usrcustomerid');
$stmt->bindValue(':expirationdate', $_SESSION['expirationdate'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':usrcustomerid', $_SESSION['usrcustomerid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$oneyear = (':expirationdate' - ':expirationdate') + 365;
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Note:

    Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2.

Comment: @tim it's weird that they have that note when 3 of their 7 examples are of mathematical operations... I will update the answer though to give an example of using `DateTime` to alter the date.

Comment: so far i got undefined index so i added: $stmt->bindValue(':expirationdate', isset($_SESSION['expirationdate']), PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: however running the answer written as of writing this comment turns my expiration date to all 0's (0000-00-00 00:00:00)

Comment: @JeremiahCanuto that won't work as it will give an empty value in the query which will cause a syntax error.

Comment: Which version of the answer are you using?

Comment: its just weird because im getting the expirationdate from $_SESSION which will be the log in of a user, it should not be empty.

Comment: Perhaps you need to `print_r($_SESSION)` to debug?

Comment: i dont know if this is a silly quesiton by, where does print_r($_SESSION) get its array? its because i seem to not have a function with the same order as print_r

Comment: [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is a PHP built-in function

Comment: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: @JeremiahCanuto sorry about that, I confused myself by putting two pieces of code in one. I've made an edit to the `DateTime` part of the code which will fix that.