# PHP get current datetime + one year (also asking if secure)

Tags: php

just trying to create a variable where it outputs the exact current datetime and adding exactly one additional year. how do i add the  days?

```
$expirationdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', .' + 1 year'));
```

- Lets say the exact current date is 2019-01-23 17:11:25
- the variable will be: 2020-01-23 17-11-25 (+365)

Also, if a person manually modifies the date on their PC/Phone, will that time be the start of the current date on the variable?

Comment: Can you write the expected output here?

Comment: added the expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [updating a datetime sql value by exactly a year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319827/updating-a-datetime-sql-value-by-exactly-a-year)

Comment: Please check the answer below

Comment: "Also, if a person manually modifies the date on their PC/Phone, will that time be the start of the current date on the variable?" -- no, the time corresponds to the time on the server machine. So they won't be able to modify it (unless the user has hacked your server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your result by using `strtotime()` and `date()` function of php

```
$expirationdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+ 1 year'));
print_r($expirationdate);
```

> You can read more about the [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
$expirationdate =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 years'));
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+1 years'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to work with dates and time in PHP is through the DateTime object. You can use `modify` method to add or subtract days, years or whatever you want, like this:

```
$d = new DateTime(); //current date
$d->modify('+10 days');
$d->modify('+1 year');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Regarding your second question if a person modifies date on his computer it won't change anything because PHP runs on the server and takes date from it (not from the user machine).